# How to access files outside the script's directory in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

Given this directory structure:

```
├── script
│   ├── search.rb
│   └── searchable.txt
└── unsearchable.txt
```

You can only search file under the script (e.g. `searchable.txt`). But how do I read `unsearchable.txt` in Ruby?
(I got this error `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - <filename>.txt`)

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: _"I want an answer that work for every file"_ – I'm not sure what that means. What's your expected output / result? It would probably help if you could show some code.

Answer (score 4):

Just one level up to your current file.

```
file = File.new('../unsearchable.txt')
```

Or

```
file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'unsearchable.txt')
```

`__FILE__` is your current file name. `..` is the parent directory.